# React Native Search using SectionList

Tags: react-native

I created a `SectionList` and tried to implement a search filter for my `SectionList`. But my output got an error. I took a screenshot of it below. I don't know what's wrong.

This is my component.

```
export default class Cluster1 extends Component{
 constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {
  dataToShow: '',
  search: false
}
} 
searchUpdated = (term) => {
let matchedItemsArray = []
if(term === ''){
  this.setState({search: false, dataToShow: ClusterData})
}else{
  this.state.dataToShow.map((item) => {
    if(item.title.includes(term)){
      matchedItemsArray.push(item)
    }
  })
  this.setState({search: true, dataToShow: matchedItemsArray})
}
}
searchUpdated = (input) => {
  let userInput =[]
if(input === ''){
  this.setState({search: false})
  userInput = ''
}else{
  this.setState({search: true})
}
}
render(){       
 return(        
     <View style={styles.container}>         
    <TextInput 
      onChangeText={(term) => { this.searchUpdated(text) }} 
      style={styles.searchInput}
      placeholder="Type a mood to search"
      />        
      <SectionList
          renderItem = {({item, index}) => 
           <SectionListItem item = {item} index = {index}/>}
          renderSectionHeader = {({section}) => 
         <SectionHeader 

            sections={this.searchUpdated()}
           keyExtractor = {(item) => item.name}/>}>
          </SectionList>     </View>
 );
 }} 

class SectionHeader extends Component {
 render() {        
     return (            
         <View style={styles.header}>  
             <Text style={styles.headertext}>
             {this.props.section.title}       
             </Text>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => Actions.SongList({ section: this.props.section}) }>
               <Text style ={styles.Play}> Play
               </Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>

         </View>
     );  }
  }
class SectionListItem extends Component{
 render(){       
     return(
         <View>
         <Text style={styles.moodname}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
         </View>
     );
 }}
```

This is my data

```
const ClusterData = [
{ title: 'Cluster1', 
data: 
[
{name: 'passionate'},{name: 'rousing'},{name: 'confident'},
{name: 'boisterous'},{name: 'rowdy'}],
},
{ 
 title: 'Cluster2', 
 data: 
[
 {name: 'rollicking'},{name: 'cheerful'{name: 'fun'},{name: 'sweet'},
{name: 'amiable'},{name: 'natured'}],
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple search filter:

I added a `search` state to help determine whether the user is currently searching or not.

```js
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dataToShow: '',
      search: false
    }
  }
```

Then, we create the search function.

```js
  searchUpdated = (term) => {
    let matchedItemsArray = []
    if(term === ''){
      this.setState({search: false, dataToShow: ClusterData})
    }else{
      this.state.dataToShow.map((item) => {
        if(item.title.includes(term)){
          matchedItemsArray.push(item)
        }
      })
      this.setState({search: true, dataToShow: matchedItemsArray})
    }
  }
```

When the input is '', the search state is false. Otherwise, the function will map through the dataToShow array to find if any section titles include the user's input.

Alternatively, I like to use a lodash filter instead for it's simplicity.
First, we declare a constant called `userInput`:

```js
let userInput
```

Then, we create a function to determine whether the userInput is empty or not to set the `search` state. (Remember to keep this.state.search that we created in the first place)

```js
  searchUpdated = (input) => {
    if(input === ''){
      this.setState({search: false})
      userInput = ''
    }else{
      this.setState({search: true})
    }
  }
```

Finally, in our SectionList we use the lodash filter to help filter for the right section header names:

```js
<SectionList
  renderItem = {({item, index}) => 
    <SectionListItem item = {item} index = {index}/>}
  renderSectionHeader = {({section}) => 
    <SectionHeader 
      section = {section}
      sections = {
        this.state.search ? 
        _.filter(this.state.dataToShow, function(item){
          return item.title.includes(userInput)}) 
        : this.state.dataToShow}
      keyExtractor = {(item) => item.name}/>}>
</SectionList>
```

The entire component

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, SectionList, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native'

const ClusterData = [
  {title: 'Cluster1', data: [{name: 'passionate'},{name: 'rousing'},{name: 'confident'},{name: 'boisterous'},{name: 'rowdy'}]},
  {title: 'Cluster2', data: [{name: 'rollicking'},{name: 'cheerful'},{name: 'fun'},{name: 'sweet'},{name: 'amiable'},{name: 'natured'}]}
]

let userInput = ''

export default class TempScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search: false,
      dataToShow: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({dataToShow: ClusterData})
  }

  searchUpdated = (term) => {
    let matchedItemsArray = []
    if(term === ''){
      this.setState({search: false, dataToShow: ClusterData})
    }else{
      this.setState({search:true, dataToShow: ClusterData}, function(){
        this.state.dataToShow.map((item) => {
          if(item.title.includes(term)){
            matchedItemsArray.push(item)
          }
        })
        this.setState({dataToShow:matchedItemsArray})
      })
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput 
          onChangeText={(term) => {this.searchUpdated(term)}} 
          style={styles.searchInput}
          placeholder="Type a mood to search"/>        
        <SectionList
          renderItem={({item}) => <SectionListItem itemName = {item.name}/>}
          renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <SectionHeader sectionTitle = {section.title}/>}
          sections={this.state.dataToShow}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class SectionHeader extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <View>
          <Text>{this.props.sectionTitle}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>Play</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

class SectionListItem extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.itemName}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: how do it map() it anywhere I can reference this to? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: My typo was not the curly braces. I still can't use the search filter

Comment: Please check my updated answer and see if it works or not. Btw would you mind explaining what `this.filterArray(text)` in your `textInput` is? Since your search function is called `searchUpdated()`, shouldn't you be doing `this.searchUpdated(text)` instead? Also, you may need to change the user's input to all lower case or upper case and compare it with the section titles transformed to all lower case or upper case as well.

Comment: I updated my coding and followed your insruction but it is still the same `props.sections.reduce`

Comment: Yeah it is supposed to be `this.searchcUpdated(text) my bad

Comment: Did it work after you changed it to `this.searchUpdated(text)`?

Comment: No it is still the same

Comment: You can see on top I have updated the codes but the output is still `props.sections.reduce`

Comment: Okay I literally wrote the entire component, please put in all the styling yourself. Btw, be aware that you can either do the first search function or you can use a lodash filter. It doesn't make sense to have two functions with the exact same name does it? Which function would the machine know to call? Tell me if it works. Also you had several typos in your code. Message me if you need any further help

Comment: The search filter works but one problem. It search for title: `Cluster1` and title: `Cluster2` instead of data: [{name: `passionate`},{name: `rousing`}

Comment: Thanks for your help I really really appreaciate it!

Comment: So what is it that you actually want to do? For example the user searches: 'happy'. You want to display the section with 'happy' in it, or you want to just display 'happy'?

Comment: When user searches: 'happy'. I want to display the section with 'happy' in it

Comment: Ok so you will want to map the entire array, then map each section's data and find if item.name matches the user's input. If it does add the section to the matchedItemsArray and display that

Comment: Okay thanks. Anyway I can contact you if I faced any other problem in terms of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const sectionList = [{
    caption: 'caption1',
    data: [{
        id: '1',
        title: 'title1',
        description: 'pay ipsum 0 !',
    }, {
        id: '2',
        title: 'title2',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum 1 !',
    }, {
        id: '3',
        title: 'title3',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum 2',
    }, {
        id: '4',
        title: 'title4',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum 3',
    }, ],
},
{
    caption: 'caption2',
    data: [{
        id: '5',
        title: 'title5',
        description: 'Custom desc',
    }, {
        id: '9',
        title: 'title5',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum 5',
    }, ],
},
];
const query = 'Lorem ipsum 5'

const res = sectionList
.map(d => ({
    ...d,
    data: d.data.filter(c => c.description.includes(query))
}))
.filter(d => d.data.length)

console.log(res);
```

Now here's how implemented the search in react-native
[sectionlist-example-with-search EXPO](https://snack.expo.dev/@sahilkash/sectionlist-example-with-search)