# React Native SectionList (title, data) - Search in the data field

Tags: react-native, search, react-native-sectionlist

I am trying to build Search function in SectionList. I have search inside the 'data' (second field) and not inside 'title' but I am not able to make it work.

My Data is about the Flat / resident details of an Apartment -

```
sectiondata =

    [{"title":"GROUND FLOOR",
      "data":[
          {"id":"48","res_type":"owner","user_name":"Ashwani","flat_id":"1","flat_name":"001","floor_no":"GROUND FLOOR","floor_int":"0","signal_player_id":"aa","user_phone":"98855550"},
          {"id":"49","res_type":"owner","user_name":"Rahul","flat_id":"2","flat_name":"002","floor_no":"GROUND FLOOR","floor_int":"0","signal_player_id":"aa","user_phone":"999999"}
        ]
    }]
```

I am trying something like this but it is not working.

```
searchFilterFunction = (text) => {

    let search = text.toLowerCase();
    this.setState({
        check: this.state.sectiondata.filter(
              obj => obj.data['flat_name'].toLowerCase().includes(search))
    });
}
```

How to filter data base on name? Please assist here.
Thanks.

Comment: This might help for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493854/react-native-search-using-sectionlist

Comment: Thank you Mitesh for your reply. That post is searching from 'title' but I want to search from 'data.flat_name'.  There the code checks like: if(item.title.includes(term))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchFilterFunction(text) {

  if( text == undefined || text == '') {
    this.setState({
      sectiondata: this.arrayholder
    })
    return;
  }

  if (text.trim().length > 0) {
      var temp = []
      this.state.sectiondata.map((item) => {
            var dataItem = {};

            var title = item.title;
            var brandData = [];

            item.data.map((searchItem) => {
              let flatName =  searchItem.flat_name
                if (flatName.match(text)) {
                  brandData.push(searchItem);
                }
            })
            if (brandData.length > 0) {

            } else {
              return null;
            }
            dataItem.title = title;
            dataItem.data = brandData;
            temp.push(dataItem);
            this.setState({
              sectiondata: temp
            })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search like this:

```
onChangeText(text) {
    if (text.trim().length > 0) {
      var temp = []
      sectiondata.map((item) => {
        var dataItem = {};

        var brandData = [];
        item.data.map((searchItem) => {
    let flatName =  searchItem.flat_name
          if (flatName.match(text)) {
            brandData.push(searchItem);
          }
        })
        if (brandData.length > 0) {

        } else {
          return null;
        }
        dataItem.brandData = brandData;
        temp.push(dataItem);
        this.setState({
          sectiondata: temp
        })
      })

    } else {
      this.setState({
        sectiondata: this.state.tempData
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks again Mitesh. I am getting errors. I checked, the onChange function is not returning 'title'. Please note that there could be multiple floors (title).

sectiondata sent by onChange function

[{
"brandData":[
  {"id":"48","res_type":"owner","user_name":"Ashwani","flat_id":"1","flat_name":"001","floor_no":"GROUND FLOOR","floor_int":"0","signal_player_id":"aa","user_phone":"98803640"},   {"id":"49","res_type":"owner","user_name":"Rahul","flat_id":"2","flat_name":"002","floor_no":"GROUND FLOOR","floor_int":"0","signal_player_id":"aa","user_phone":"999999"}
     ]
}]